# What's use of external table in HIVE?

Tags: hive, hiveql

I want to create an external table in hive for my own table. 
So how can i proceed to do the same?

External table details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Major advantage of using External table is.. you are avoiding ETL.

Drop the files in a folder and create a Table as wrapper around it.

If you have sub folders you can create partitions in your table creation and data is available right away.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a query like below,

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE <table_name> 
AS
SELECT * FROM <source_table>
LOCATION '<HDFS_PATH>'
```

OR

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS <table_name> (
  col1        datatype,
  col2        datatype)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LOCATION '<HDFS PATH>';
```